# why evaluateJavascript is getting iterated inside handler(Android)?

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, webview

I want to evaluate a javascript in Webview Android as given below in the code. I want to evaluate it after 3 seconds. It works, it gets evaluated after 3 seconds but it(the code inside run()) keeps repeating after every 3 seconds in an infinite loop.
**I just want to evaluate it once after 3 seconds**

```
                    int delay = 3000;
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Reached",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            final String js3 = "javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('icon')[0].click();";
                            view.evaluateJavascript(js3,null);
                        }
                    },delay);
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //webview
    private WebView webView;
    private String uname,password;
    private int x=0;
    private  CountDownTimer timer;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

       
        final String password = "Pass@123";
        final String username = "111111111";
        //url
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://something.com/xyz/abc/student2020.html#");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                final String js = "javascript:" +
                        "document.getElementById('phone_1').value = '" + username + "';"  +
                        "document.getElementById('submit_1').click()";

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                    view.evaluateJavascript(js,null);

                            final String js2 = "javascript:"+"document.getElementById('pass_2').value = '"+password+"';"
                                    + "document.getElementById('phone_2').value = '" + username + "';"
                                    + "javascript:document.getElementById('submit_2').click()";
                            view.evaluateJavascript(js2,null);
                            

                    int delay = 3000;
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Reached",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            final String js3 = "javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('icon')[0].click();";
                            view.evaluateJavascript(js3,null);
                        }
                    },delay);

                } else {
                    view.loadUrl(js);

                }
            }
        });
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show how do you runn posted snippet, probably in some method called multiple times. `Handler` with `postDelayed` will call only once, won't be repeated/looped

Comment: @snachmsm I have added my MainActivity.java above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

calling `evaluateJavascript` will make `onPageFinished` to be called further, in which you are setting, again, your `Handler`

simplest way to avoid this is introducing some `boolean` which will be flagged after evaluating JS and prevent second and further calls

```
private WebView webView;
private String uname,password;
private int x=0;
private  CountDownTimer timer;
private boolean jsExecuted = false;
```

in callback

```
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            if (jsExecuted) return;
            jsExecuted = true
            // JS execution code
        }
```

btw. you have probably some bug in flow for <19, only first JS will be loaded/executed

Answer (score 0):

You're performing an click() inside your code which causes the page to be rendered again which then starts the whole process again causing it to run forever.

After performing click(), return false and this should stop the browser reloading.

e.g.change

```
document.getElementById('submit_1').click()
```

to

```
document.getElementById('submit_1').click(); return false;
```

You will need to do this on all instances where you call click().

Comment: only first JS is getting loaded/executed